# cmake: variable has appended strings from SET contents, can't use for args in add_custom_command

Tags: cmake

I have an external file named `images.list` with following contents:

```
find "file1.png" add "file2.png"
```

In my cmake script I grab the file contents with this:

```
file(READ "images.list" FILE_CONTENTS)
```

And I create a list or arguments with this:

```
set(CMD_ARGS --raw --build-list ${FILE_CONTENTS} > "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/image.h")
```

Later I use `CMD_ARGS`:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/image.h"
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/images.list"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${DATADIR}
    COMMAND gdk-pixbuf-csource
    ARGS ${CMD_ARGS}
    COMMENT "Compilando GLIB resources..."
)
```

This code works as expected in my Windows 7, but not on Linux: a blank image.h file is created. I debug `CMD_ARGS` and I see the strings are appended and also cmake include some `\` but not in Windows:

```
--raw--build-listfind \ "file1.png"
```

Which I expect like this for `CMD_ARGS`:

```
--raw --build-list find "file1.png" add "file2.png" > "/a/nice/path/image.h"
```

So, whay would be the proper way to grab external file contents and use it as arguments? Any one can help on this?

**Updated**:
We must use something like this:

```
file(READ ${GRESOURCE_FILE_SRC} FILE_CONTENTS)
# Visit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72735157/2030219
separate_arguments(FILE_CONTENTS_PROCESSED NATIVE_COMMAND ${FILE_CONTENTS})
set(CMD_ARGS --raw --build-list ${FILE_CONTENTS_PROCESSED} > "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/images.h")
```

in order to get platform-independent file contents as command arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`separate_arguments` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/separate_arguments.html) to make sure the file contents are converted to a list variable:

```
file(READ "images.list" FILE_CONTENTS)

message("FILE_CONTENTS:")
set(CMD_ARGS --raw --build-list ${FILE_CONTENTS} > "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/image.h")
foreach(ELEMENT IN LISTS CMD_ARGS)
    message("${ELEMENT}")
endforeach()

separate_arguments(FILE_CONTENTS_PROCESSED UNIX_COMMAND ${FILE_CONTENTS})

message("FILE_CONTENTS_PROCESSED:")
set(CMD_ARGS --raw --build-list ${FILE_CONTENTS_PROCESSED} > "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/image.h")
foreach(ELEMENT IN LISTS CMD_ARGS)
    message("${ELEMENT}")
endforeach()
```

**Output**

```
FILE_CONTENTS:
--raw
--build-list
find "file1.png" add "file2.png"
>
.../image.h
FILE_CONTENTS_PROCESSED:
--raw
--build-list
find
file1.png
add
file2.png
>
.../image.h
```

You can see that the file contents are no longer treated as a single string after applying `separate_arguments` so it should work properly for passing multiple arguments to `add_custom_command`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: I updated my question with correct usage. A quick one more question: from `file(READ "images.list" FILE_CONTENTS)`, **${FILE_CONTENTS}** is updated everytime I modified images.list file? It seems that I need to rebuild the cmakecache in order to get the lastest contest.

Comment: @Joel `file(READ)` is only executed during a reconfiguration of the cmake project which does not automatically happen on a change of `images.list`. If you want to change this, you could add the file to the [`CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` directory property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html) or use `add_custom_command` to run a cmake script file and move the `COMMAND` to a `execute_process` call in that script along with the logic to extract the file contents.